# How to prove (A ⊆ B) ∧ (B ⊆ C) ⇒ (A ⊆ C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How would I go about proving that, given A, B, C are sets;

$[(A⊆B)∧(B⊆C)]⇒(A⊆C)$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What's the definition of “being a subset of”?

Comment: Yes, just wondering if it is enough proof to say that: If there is an $x$ in B such that, for every $x$ in B, $x$ is in C and there exists an $x$ in A such that, for every $x$ in A, $x$ is in B. Thus, for every $x$ in A, $x$ is also in C, and therefore A is a subset of C.

Comment: You're doing it in a rather confuse way; what do you mean by “there is an $x\in B$ such that, for every $x\in B$, …”?

Comment: "If there is an x in B such that, for every x in B" is already meaningless, because you have chosen x twice -- first with an existential quantifier, and then again with a universal quantifier.

Comment: Sorry wasn't sure if you could use $\in$ in the comments. Would have been easier to write.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

You want to start with $a\in A$, and try to use the assumptions you're given to show that $a\in C$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $(A\subseteq B)\wedge (B\subseteq C)$ is true. Then both $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq C$ are true.  Let $x\in A$ be chosen arbitrarily.  Since $A\subseteq B$, we conclude that $x\in B$.  Since $B\subseteq C$, we conclude that $x\in C$.  Since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that $A\subseteq C$.

Based on the hypothesis $(A\subseteq B)\wedge (B\subseteq C)$, we have concluded $(A\subseteq C)$.  Hence we have proved that $(A\subseteq B)\wedge (B\subseteq C)\to (A\subseteq C)$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that it is not true.

So we have:

$A\subseteq B \land B\subseteq C \land (\lnot  A\subseteq C)$

$ (x\in A \implies x\in B) \land (x\in B \implies x\in C) \land x\in A \land x\notin C $

and :

$( (x\in A \implies x\in B) \land x\in A ) \implies x \in B$

so:

$ x \in B \land (x\in B \implies x\in C) \land x\in A \land x\notin C $

then:

$((x∈B⟹x∈C)∧x∈A)⟹x∈C$

ans we have:

$ x \in B \land x∈C \land x\in A \land x\notin C $

$  x∈C \land  x\notin C $ isn't true,

so $\lnot$ [(A ⊆ B)∧(B ⊆ C) → (A⊆C)] is false

and (A ⊆ B)∧(B ⊆ C) → (A⊆C) is true

Answer (score 0):

For any $x\in A$, since $A\subset B$, we have that $x\in B$. Note that $B\subset C$, then we can derive that $x\in C$. This shows that $A\subset C$.